# pyside - how to capture capital letter (KeyEvent)?

Tags: python, event-handling, pyside, keypress

I have understood that letters to capture the event is used `keyPressEvent`.

```
def iniciar(self):
    self.resize(730, 500)
    self.setFixedSize(730, 500)
    self.center()
    self.setWindowTitle('Practico 1')
    self.show() 

def center(self):
    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())

def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'pressed', 'you pressed the letter "a"')
```

This way I capture letters either in uppercase or lowercase, but how should I verify a capital letter has been pressed?

Comment: Do you want to force the user to just enter capital letters or you want to perform a reaction when the user enters a capital letter and ignore other inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check uppercase using modifiers. For instance with

```
if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A and (e.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.SHIFT):
```